# rearrange the output of the aggregate function into a new table

Tags: r

I have a data set that describes some locations. I aggregate some response metric y within some locations according a categorical predictor, p. I get this type of dataframe as an output

```
location<-c('site1','site1','site1','site2','site2','site3','site3','site3','site3')
p<-c('A','B','C','A','B','A','B','C','D')
y<-c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4)

data.frame(location,p,y)
```

what I want is a data frame that looks like this

```
p<-c('A','B','C','D')
site1<-c(1,2,3,NA)
site2<-c(1,2,NA,NA)
site3<-c(1,2,3,4)

data.frame(p,site1,site2,site3)
```

is there a simple way to do this in R?

Comment: What a nicely reproducible question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df1 <- data.frame(location,p,y)
library(reshape2)
dcast(df1, p ~ location, value.var = "y")

##   p site1 site2 site3
## 1 A     1     1     1
## 2 B     2     2     2
## 3 C     3    NA     3
## 4 D    NA    NA     4
```

Comment: this totally works, but the repsonse G. Grothendieck does not require installing a package.

Answer (score 2):

`tapply` can do that.  The first argument goes in the body of the table and the second argument specifies the rows and and columns:

```
tapply(DF[[3]], DF[2:1], c)
```

giving:

```
   location
p   site1 site2 site3
  A     1     1     1
  B     2     2     2
  C     3    NA     3
  D    NA    NA     4
```

This can also be written:

```
with(DF, tapply(y, data.frame(p, location), c))
```

Comment: i prefer this as it does not require installing a package, however when I run this I get ABCD as the column headings, and site 1-3 as the rows in the first column. Because the code you rpvoide for tapply is not very intuitive- i do not know how to rewrite the above command based on what is here- its not useful for my purpose.

Comment: I have rewritten the query to give A, B, C, D as rows rather than columns, have added some explanation and also an alternative `tapply` expression.